# Binary search to determine where to place value

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, binary-search-tree

I'm writing c++ code to implement a hash map using various techniques (arrays, binary tree, etc). I got stuck at implementation by array. I need a way to determine where to place the new hash in such a way that the array is sorted after it is placed. My idea is to use binary search to determine the index at which to place the new hash, and then push all other elements.

I'm having a problem with that function. It should have some prototype like this:

```
int WhereToPlaceHash(HashType hash); // uses private atribute ValueType** values
```

I have tried my best to write this function, but all of my tries resulted in infinite loops and reading invalid locations from the array. Please help.

Comment: I can't understand your question, in hashtables you don't need to "search" for a value, you just calculate the index using some hash function and then make modulo the size of the array, and the value should be there. if two values are hashed to the same index you can put a linked list in that index.

Comment: I'm not yet using any hash functions. Just plain index searching.
Problem is actually how to determine where to place new value in sorted array (using bin-search).

Comment: If you included the best of your attempts so far at writing this function, it would be easier for us to get a sense of what your current lines of thinking are.

Comment: "implement a hash map using various techniques" - a hash map is by definition implemented with a hash table. The abstract data type of a mapping may be implemented a number of ways, but a hash map is a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the hash is used as an index into an array. Also, when using hashes you may get an array sorted by the hashes but not by the keys (it's kind of obvious, though). If you really want to find the location where a key should go in a sorted array, you'd use `std::lower_bound()`:

```
int* pos = std::lower_bound(array, array + array_size, key);
```

The return iterator `pos` will point at the first location such that `!(key < *pos)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a **set** of different implementation types

**map** contain a key and value pair - you only have a key - so it is a **set**

**hash** means a different thing - they are unordered and use a hash function to select a bucket for a list of all items with the same hash, called collisions (some variants use other schemes to deal with collisions).  This is implented in the STL as `std::unordered_set`, `std::unsordered_map`, ...

For an array implementation that is sorted use an array that is kept in sorted array, and then do an insert that has to shift all items greater to maintain the sort order.  Your lookup will then do a binary search

The insert will use binary search to find where to place the item, and then shift all items greater than it.

The binary search, starts at the middle and then repetively checks (low+mid)/2 if lower or (mid+highest)/2 if greater until the location is found

Note you will have to distinguish between found and not found

```
int binsearch(int * array, int len, int value, bool * found)
{
    // return lowest position greater or equal to value

    int lowp=0;
    int highp=len-1;
    int midp=(lowp+highp)/2;

    while (lowp <=highp)
    {
        int mid=array[midp];
        if (mid > value)
        {
            highp=midp-1;
        }
        else if (value==mid)
        {
            *found=true;
            return midp; // found at this position
        }
        else
        {
            lowp=midp+1;
        }
        midp=(lowp+highp)/2;
    }
    *found=false;
    if (array[midp] > value)
    {
        return midp;  // only at position 0 for a head insert
    }
    return midp+1; // not found - position to start shift
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int array[]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    bool found;

    for (int search=1; search < 22; ++search)
    {
        int a=binsearch(array, 10, search, &found);

        std::cout << search << " at " << a << ":" << found << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is actually how to determine where to place new value in sorted array (using bin-search). Sorry for the confision.

Answer (score 0):

Read this attentively:
[binary search wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

and try something like this:

```
int WhereToPlaceHash(int hash) {
    int imin = 0, imax = YourSizeOfArray;
    int imid = 0;

  while (imax >= imin) {
      imid = (imax + imin) / 2;

      if(YourArray[imid] == hash)
        return imid + 1; 
      else if (YourArray[imid] < hash)
        break;
      else         
        imax = imid - 1;
    }

  return imid;
}
```